# Setup.exe is rolling back (Built for Asp.net Application In Install Shield12)

Tags: iis, installation, virtual-directory, installshield-2010, installshield-2012

I build Setup.exe file in Install Shield 12 for Web Project  of .Net Framework.
When i m going to run this setup.exe file , i got rolling back error while execute Virtual Directory and setup had not been completed.
How could i resolve this Rolling Back error due to Virtual Directory ?
With which application of install shield this issues is connected ?

Comment: Are you running the installer as administrator?

Comment: I m installing in Windows server 2003 on /virtual machine.

Comment: @Problems: But... are you running *as an administrator*?  That is, is your current user context permitted to create virtual directories in IIS?  When logged in, can you create one manually?

Comment: Yes.I m running as administrator ...but something wrong to setup virtual directory...i created new .exe file once again.but still same error.There are some settings related to virtual directory, with which i m not aware ...i trying to solve it...

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out what the actual error is that is causing the rollback to occur. 
To do this, you'll want the installer to create a log for you.

You can do this by running the exe like this:

```
setup /V"/L*v c:\everything.log"
```

Then, look through the log file and find out where it decides to rollback (searching for "rollback", then looking just above that should get you close.)

Comment: And yes , Mr. Lynn, i m getting this error during creating virtual directory.....

Comment: @Problems: Can you just open the log file in Notepad?  Or is it something other than just text?

Comment: @Problems: Can you copy and paste the part of the log where the error occurs? Edit your question, and add it, and we'll see what it says.